# remove relative path of a jar and keep only jar name

Tags: ant

I Have a property file which contains list of jars from different paths like this

```
/gwt/X/2.1.0/gwt-servlet.jar                                    
/gwt/X/2.1.0/gwt-user.jar
/gwt/X/2.1.0/gwt-dev.jar    
/gwt/X/2.1.0/gwt-soyc-vis.jar 
/log4j/X/1.2.15/log4j-1.2.15.jar
/GWT_LOG/X/3.0.3/gwt-log-3.0.3.jar
/GWT_MATH/X/2.1/gwt-math-2.1.jar
/GWT_MATH/X/2.1/gwt-math-server-2.1.jar 
/GWT_Commons_Logging/X/0.3/GWT-commons-logging/gwt-commons-logging-0.3.jar          
/GWT_Commons_Logging/X/0.3/GWT-commons-logging/gwt-commons-logging-service-0.3.jar
```

I have around 1000 jars like this in this list. 
I would like to remove relative paths before jar name and out put jar names in a new file some thing like this

```
gwt-servlet.jar             
gwt-user.jar
gwt-dev.jar 
gwt-soyc-vis.jar 
log4j-1.2.15.jar
gwt-log-3.0.3.jar
gwt-math-2.1.jar
gwt-math-server-2.1.jar 
gwt-commons-logging-0.3.jar     
gwt-commons-logging-service-0.3.jar
```

This is not a one time activity, so i would like to create a target or task in My build.xml for daily usage.

Answer (score 1):

```
 <replaceregexp file="file.txt" match="[^ ]*/" replace="" byline="true" flags="g"/>
```

Comment: If this answer solved your problem, you should click the checkbox next to the answer to "accept" it.

Answer (score 0):

Ant isn't well suited for tasks like this. It's probably much more simple to write a simple Ant Task in Java for that (or a small Java program; just create `File` objects and invoke `getName()` to get the last path element).

But if you have to: [`script`](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/script.html) and [`scriptdef`](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/scriptdef.html) are probably your friends (provided that your version of Ant is recent enough; the docs mention 1.6.3). You can call any Java method from these scripts. See the [manual](http://ant.apache.org/manual/tasklist.html) for examples.